# What we do when a Domain Controller crash?(Windows)

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain-controller

Assuming that we have only one domain controllers were present in network, what steps need to be taken to restore the network after a domain controller crash?

1. Configuring RODC is a good way to recover from crash?
2. Is configure ADC is a good way?
   3.Is there any other solution to recover when DC crashes
   Which is the best way to recover when Domain controller crash.

Comment: Restore from backup, and then when that's done, make sure you have at least two DCs on two separate pieces of hardware.

Comment: Having two separate DC for a small company is a good way? The  First scenario is

The domain controller is down when there is no IT admin at office,. Is there any way that won't effect the working of employee. I mean What we have a RODC? 

The Second Scenario is

The domain controller is down due to hardware failure, having two Dc is good but its a small company around 50 employee so do we need two domain in our network.

Comment: Absolutely. Any AD deployment should have two DCs.

Comment: Don't bother with RODCs. Create two full domain controllers.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.    Do we need to up two DC's same time or one is online other should keep offline. When the crash occur put online the second dc?

Comment: OK. Stop flailing around and spend some time reading about Active Directory. No, you do not keep a DC "offline". Both stay online 100% of the time, both field authentication requests from clients, and perform bi-directional replication between them.

Comment: @Nithinkn: If you don't have another functioning Domain Controller and if you don't have a System State backup of the failed Domain Controller then you're going to have to start from scratch. You may want to enlist the services of an experienced professional in getting things squared away.

Comment: Don't bother with RODCs ever- there is a very specific reason to deploy an RODC and almost no one has that situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always have two Domain Controllers. On top of that, you should also backup at least two Domain Controllers for each site.

Microsoft has lots of information on the backup and recover of AD:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771290(v=ws.10).aspx

Someone should also understand the fundamental concepts within AD. Below is a link to Microsoft's Best Practice Guide for AD. It has a lot of information, but the fundamentals are key to success and preventing horrible failure:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb727085.aspx